# How to make FujiFilm X-T20 switch between EVF and LCD based on custom distance?

Tags: fujifilm, fujifilm-x-t20

My X-T20 switches to EVF when there is an object within about 3 inches of the EVF. This often happens when I am using the LCD tilted up as a waist-level finder. I want it to only react to objects within less than an inch, since I never look through the EVF from 3-inches away. I have looked through the manual and settings and cannot find a way to do it.

How can I customize the distance at which the camera switches between LCD and EVF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such user-accessible setting, I'm afraid. This goes for higher-end models as well.

It's possible that this can be adjusted at the factory — it's worth asking Fujifilm if they can do that.

I can see how you find this annoying, but consider that the more aggressive switch means the scene is ready in the EVF without waiting once your eye *is* closer.